# AFNetworkActivityLogger's level in SWIFT

Tags: swift, afnetworking-2

I have a project in SWIFT where I use AFNetworking and AFNetworkActivityLogger for debugging. I am having troubles to change the "level" attribute. By default it is set to AFLoggerLevelInfo, but I need it to AFLoggerLevelDebug.

I tried the following in my AppDelegate.swift:

```
AFNetworkActivityLogger.sharedLogger().level = AFLoggerLevelDebug
```

which results in "**Use of unresolved identifier 'AFLoggerLevelDebug'**". Anyone knows how to change the level of AFNetworkActivityLogger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AFHTTPRequestLoggerLevel` is an `enum`, so you want:

```
AFNetworkActivityLogger.sharedLogger().level = AFHTTPRequestLoggerLevel.AFLoggerLevelDebug
```

or

```
AFNetworkActivityLogger.sharedLogger().level = .AFLoggerLevelDebug
```